# How-to use "browser", not "main" entry point of npm dependency in nativescript

Tags: node.js, plugins, npm, nativescript, package.json

I have a NPM package that serves shared code, for browsers and backends. It is being used in node environments and on clients, or both, e.g. in meteor.

Its simplified package.json looks like this :

```
{
  "name": "@smallstack/core",
  "version": "0.8.0",
  "main": "./server.umd.js",
  "types": "./dts/index.d.ts",
  "browser": "./browser.umd.js"
}
```

Meteor for example uses "main" on server side and "browser" on client side. If I use the same package in nativescript I would have expected that it loads the "browser" entry point, unfortunately it loads the "main" entry point which leads to wrong results and a lot of errors.

Is it possible to specify which entry point is being used? Or am I miss-using "browser" and "main"?

Is there maybe an undocumented property in the "nativescript" section in the package.json?

Comment: I had done libraries with two entry points, but that was `bin` to be called when library is called via CLI and normal `main`. The `browser` is new to me. Does it have to be browserified anyway? Because if so, you would build a separate bundle for those environments, and call manually from HTML, not via `package.json`..

Comment: Right, "bin" is another one. It gets bundled into an UMD module which should get loaded together with the NPM dependencies as NPM Module. Otherwise I would have to sync dependency changes.